# jQuery Mobile 1.0 anchor tag not loading page for same URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, anchor

I've noticed that with jQuery Mobile, if an anchor tag's href is the same as the current URL, the page does not refresh, as it does normally.  I'm using a Stepped Wizard through a series of pages, and the final page has a link to repeat the process; this works fine except in jQuery Mobile.  I'm new to the Mobile framework, so I'm not sure what events are firing that I need to hook into.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a glimpse of the controller/ view code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var model = new MyViewModel();
   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      switch (model.SubmitButton)
      {
         case Buttons.Review:
            return Review(model);
         case Buttons.Confirm:
            return Confirm(model);
      }
   }
return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Review(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View("Review", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Confirm(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Confirm", model);
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
   @* display stuff *@
   @Html.ActionLink("Do it again!", "Index", "MyController", new { area = "MyArea" }, new { data_role = "button" })
   @* display more stuff *@
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the code you posted is not javascript and for sure not using JQM..... Is that your aspx code-behind?

Either way, you'll probably want to disable JQM's ajaxEnabled loading if you want to reload the whole page in the current browser window.

See [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html)